# how to wait until the textbox enable in watin

Tags: asp.net, watin

i have one textbox on my page on the load event textbox is disable for 10 then its enable
so how to wait for 10 sec in watin.
i am try to this code

```
IE ie = new IE("http://localhost:2034/WebForm3.aspx");
         ie.ShowWindow(WatiN.Core.Native.Windows.NativeMethods.WindowShowStyle.Maximize);
         ie.TextField("TextBox1").TypeText("Fer");
```

but it gives the error that TextBox1 is disable so i want to wait for some time.
so how to do this?
please help me?

Comment: is the code what you have posted javascript? or server side code or any other script? Also Please make the question clear..

Answer (score 0):

You can just sleep the thread for a fixed amount of time in order for the test to wait:

```
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

The time is in milliseconds. Maybe you would need to increase that number a little bit, but still this should work.

Comment: Sleeping works for an arbitrarily large-ish amount of time works, but is inefficient as you'll end up waiting longer than needed.  Works, but not great.

Answer (score 0):

If it is ran when the webpage loads you could probably just use this:

```
ie.WaitForComplete();
```

Wait for complete will make the test wait until all of the elements and frames are loaded before carrying out the next task, in your case locating the textbox for input.

The only problem I have with putting the thread to sleep is that it can take a bit longer than you may need. This way you know it is running as soon as the page is done. (Which may vary a bit).

Answer (score 0):

Two *better* ways than just using a long Thread.Sleep() to wait for fields to enable due to a script or asnyc call; eg Ajax.   (Note: I'd be ashamed to admit how many long Thread.Sleeps() I have in my code.)

The below are both referencing a checkbox, but the same concepts should work just fine on a textbox or other control.

1)  Check the disabled attribute.

```
myPage.myCheckbox.WaitUntil("disabled", false.ToString())
```

2) Poll the field, sleeping a short amount of time at each check.   I did this poll pattern as the above simple one liner above didn't work; I don't remember why as it has been quite a while.

```
int sleepTime = 100;
int numberOfPolls = 50;

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    if (myPage.myCheckbox.Enabled == false)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this...

```
ie.Element("TextBox1").WaitUntil<Element>(element => element.Enabled);
```