# how to wait until the textbox is enable in watin

Tags: asp.net, watin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to wait until the textbox enable in watin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699238/how-to-wait-until-the-textbox-enable-in-watin)

i have one textbox on my page on the load event textbox is disable for 10 then its enable so how to wait for 10 sec in watin. i am try to this code

for enabling and disabling the textbox on the form load event disable the text box and on on timer tick event enable the text box and disable the timer.

the timer interval is 11 sec

```
IE ie = new IE("http://localhost:2034/WebForm3.aspx");
     ie.ShowWindow(WatiN.Core.Native.Windows.NativeMethods.WindowShowStyle.Maximize);
     ie.TextField("TextBox1").TypeText("Fer");
```

but it gives the error that TextBox1 is disable so i want to wait for some time. so how to do this? please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you May try these Links for the 'wait'

[wait 1](http://forums.asp.net/t/990657.aspx/1)

[wait 2](http://forums.asp.net/t/1553037.aspx/1)

[wait 3](http://forums.asp.net/t/812298.aspx/1)

[wait 4](http://forums.asp.net/t/446710.aspx/1)

```
  <script language="JavaScript">
     function fun2()
     {
      // do your stuff here
      }

    function fun1()
     {
        // do your stuff here
        window.setTimeout('fun2()', 5000);
      }
   </script>
```

**to use it is ---

```
 <body>
   <script language="JavaScript">
     fun1();
   </script>
  </body>
```

Or this [On](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/SleepNET.aspx)

```
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep()
```